# mod_rewrite "virtual subdomain" redirect not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've just moved from a Litespeed hosting to an Apache's one.
However such redirects stopped working.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nix.foo.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.nix.foo.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.foo\.com\/nix\.php" [R=301,L]
```

On Firefox, I get a "failed to connect to the server" message.
I tried simpler mod_rewrite redirects such as

```
RewriteRule ^foo.php$ bar.php
```

and they work, so mod_rewrite seems to be already enabled thanks to `RewriteEngine on`.

Any hints?
Thanks

edit: It seems that all I had to do was creating an empty "nix" folder, and the redirect worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all I had to do was creating an empty "nix" folder, and the redirect worked.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your problem has been resolved but just a couple of things to note here.

You need the escapes in your `RewriteCond` not in the `RewriteRule` or the `.` would accept any character in its place like `nixxfoo.com`. You can also club your two `HTTP_HOST` conditions into one and there's no need to capture the URL with `(.*)` since it's not being referred to during substitution.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?nix\.foo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.foo.com/nix.php [R=301,L]
```